# Run CMD in VB.Net using files as StandardInput and StandardOutput

Tags: vb.net, cmd, process

I'm trying to run a command in VB.Net such as:

```
my_program.exe < input_commands.txt > console_outputs.txt
```

I tried using the RedirectStandardInput :

```
myProcessStartInfo.FileName = programPath
myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
myprocess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo
myprocess.Start()
```

And a StreamWriter to input my text file :

```
Dim myStreamWriter As StreamWriter = myprocess.StandardInput
For Each Line As String In System.IO.File.ReadLines(processInputFile)
    myStreamWriter.WriteLine(Line)
Next
myStreamWriter.Close()
```

And a similar approach to get the ouputs to a file text :

```
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
Dim output As String = Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
```

But results are quite limited...

Could you please guide me toward a proper solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the following function that does the trick :

```
 Sub runProgrammCommandsInputFileResultsOutputFile(ByVal myProcessStartInfo As ProcessStartInfo, ByVal myProcess As Process, ByVal programPath As String, ByVal commandsInputFile As String, ByVal resultsOutputFile As String)
        myProcessStartInfo.FileName = programPath
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        myProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo

        myProcess.Start()

        ' Read commands from text file
        Dim readCommandsInputFile() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(commandsInputFile)

        ' Open StreamWriter to StandardInput
        Dim myStreamWriter As StreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput

        ' Write read commands to Streamwriter openned to StandardInput
        For Each s As String In readCommandsInputFile
            myStreamWriter.WriteLine(s)
        Next

        myStreamWriter.Close()

        'Read StandardOutput
        Dim resultsOutputStrings As String = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

        ' Write StandardOutput read to text file
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(resultsOutputFile, resultsOutputStrings)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is, first read all the lines from the `input_commands.txt` file into mem:

```
Private Sub ReadInputFile(programPath as String, processInputFile as String, processOuputFile as String)

        ' Open the file to read from.
        Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines(processInputFile)

        For Each s As String In readText

            ' Run the command through the cmd process
            OutPutResults(programPath, s, processOuputFile)

        Next

End Sub
```

and output (append) the results to `console_output.txt`:

```
Private Sub OutPutResults(programPath as String, strArgument as String, processOuputFile as String)

            Dim p As New Process()

            ' Set it to run hidden from user
            With p.StartInfo
                .RedirectStandardOutput = True
                .RedirectStandardError = True
                .FileName = programPath
                .Arguments = strArgument
                .UseShellExecute = False
                .CreateNoWindow = True
            End With

            p.Start()

            ' Save all output to the variable "strOutput"
            Dim strOutput As String = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

            ' Wait for programPath .exe to finish before we handle it's output:
            ' (Sync method, meaning the thread won't continue until this one is finished. Use .exited if wanting to do Async)
            ' Also note that you can add a timeout in milliseconds to this if wanted. i.e. .WaitForExit(1000)
            p.WaitForExit()

            ' Save the output to console_output.txt
            File.AppendAllText(processOuputFile, strOutput)

End Sub
```

Note the above code is completely untested; I just whipped it up to give you the idea.

Comment: Thank you. Tested, the execution stays stuck at line `Dim strOutput As String = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`